# Merging of questions on plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, exact-duplicates

I've just voted to close

[I feel like I'm plagiarizing my story?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/34657/28912)

as a duplicate of

[I'm scared that my story is plagiarizing another story](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/20028/28912)

These two questions seem essentially identical, but they've attracted a whole bevy of answers (five on one question, three on the other) which look to be worth preserving.

**Should these two questions be merged?** Needs a mod, but I'm posting on meta instead of just flagging because I'm new to this community (not to SE) and don't know the norms here yet.

Answer (score 2):

We haven't had a lot of merges, but merges are infrequent everywhere so that's not surprising.  What we need to determine -- and this can be done by the community; it doesn't require a mod -- is: does *every* answer on both questions fit with the single question that would be the result of the merge?  I assume the surviving question would be the older one, which is a little more detailed.

Merges can't be undone by mere mortals (that would need a developer reaching directly into the database), so we want to be sure before we pull the trigger.  In the meantime, that newer question should be closed as a duplicate -- a prerequisite for merging.  I see two suggested duplicate targets, so I'm not applying the mod-hammer on that yet.

Comment: I think the two questions I've linked are *very* similar, and the answers to the newer one would all fit on the older one too. As for the one Galastel linked as a dupe target: I hadn't seen that when making this meta, and haven't checked if it's similar enough to be part of a merge. (Potentially not since Galastel's question doesn't explicitly mention plagiarism? Dunno.)

Comment: On a quick skim the other suggestion looks different enough to not be a complete dupe and merge candidate, but I haven't read everything there yet.

Comment: Agreed, let's merge these all into one canonical question.

Answer (score 1):

These two questions - yes, I think they're similar enough that, as Monica states in her answer, every answer in both questions would fit both. At least, I skimmed over them, and it seemed so.

I suggested a different duplicate in my VTC: one that was created as a canonical question, because we were seeing too many questions of the "my idea is similar to X" kind. Because it was created to be canonical, I always point similar question to it, rather than to other similar questions. The level of similarities between the questions you point to is greater, though.